# Custom Widget in Yii

Tags: php, yii, view, widget

I create new widget like this:

```
class MyMenu extends CWidget
{
    public function init()
    {

    }
    
    public function run()
    {
        $Items = array(
                    array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/site/index')),
                    array('label'=>'Add User', 'url'=>array('/user/register')),
                    array('label'=>'View Users', 'url'=>array('/user/index')),
                    array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::app()->user->isGuest),
                    array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::app()->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
                );
        $this->render('MyMenu', array('Items'=>$Items));
    }
}
```

and view for this widget

```
echo '<div id="Menu">';
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
                'items' => $Items,
        ));
echo '</div>';
```

This is paths of my widget files:

[image]

But i get error

> MyMenu Widget can not find the view "MyMenu"

What i made wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the directory `views` instead of `view`.

Source code shows it: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#getViewPath-detail

Comment: Thanks, btw. maybe you'll know why i cant get access to MyMenu.css. I renamed extensions/widgets to etensions/MyMenu and i put MyMenu.css to assets folder.  In widget's view file i made: `$filename = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/protected/extension/MyMenu/assets/MyMenu.css'; Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile($filename);`  
Core-view shows: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Nauka/protected/extension/MyMenu/assets/MyMenu.css" />` but as I said i can't get access to this css file (error 403 when i trying show this file in browser)

Comment: My mistake, i need to replace css file. It's must be located in assets folder in root, not in new assets folder in widget's folder!